# Why am I getting the scanner cannot be resolved errors on the following code in Java?

Tags: java

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Apples1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(bucky.nextln ());

}
```

}

Comment: I found this on a YouTube video and was trying to copy it to learn, but it works on the video, but not on mine.  It gives me the following errors.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
 Scanner cannot be resolved to a type
 system cannot be resolved to a variable

 at Apples1.main(Apples1.java:5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you haven't imported `Scanner`. You have tried importing `scanner`, which **does not exist**.Try doing

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

Also, the `System.in` also has a **Capital S** in the beginning.*Lastly*, there doesn't exist `nextln` method in the `Scanner` class. I suppose you intended doing :

```
System.out.println(bucky.nextLine());
```

Comment: I did import the scanner.  For some reason it didn't show it in the gray box, but it is there before the code starts.  I changed it to the capital S on the system and on the import scanner at the top and it still doesn't work.

Comment: To keep from adding another short answer, System also must be capitalized in System.in

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
public class Apples1 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println(bucky.nextln ());

 }

}

Comment: @GrantaOmega See my answer now. There doesn't exist a `nextln` method in the `Scanner` class.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!